# How to limit the RAM used by Apache Tomcat on AWS micro instance?

Tags: tomcat, memory

I am running Apache Tomcat with Geoserver as a `.WAR` on an AWS micro server running Ubuntu 14.04 with 1 GB RAM and ~700 MB swap, and I am concerned about my RAM usage because it is overflowing into my swap space.

Here are the first two distinct commands running in my `htop`, sorted by `MEM%`:

```
  CPU[|                                                                              0.7%]     Tasks: 80, 289 thr; 1 running
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||770/992MB]     Load average: 0.00 0.01 0.05
  Swp[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                         369/634MB]     Uptime: 43 days, 12:50:37
  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
16050 tomcat     20   0 1710M  586M  4584 S  0.0 59.1  0:04.48 jsvc.exec -java-home /opt/bitnami/java -user tomcat -pidfile /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/temp/catalina.pid -wait 10 -outfile /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/logs/catalina-daemon.out -errfile &1 -classpath /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/bin/commons-daemon.jar:/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/conf/logging.properties -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xms256M -Xmx512M -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseG1GC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -Dcatalina.base=/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
(x50)
1521 mysql      20   0  273M  8296     0 S  0.0  0.8  1:59.92 /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin --defaults-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/my.cnf --basedir=/opt/bitnami/mysql --datadir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --lower-case-table-names=1 --log-error=/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log --pid-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysql/data/mysqld.pid --socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock --port=3306
(x16)
```

where I added `(x50)` to indicate 50 distinct Tomcat PID's with the same command, and `(x16)` to indicate 16 distinct MySQL processes. Since the `mysql` command uses only `0.8 MEM%~`, I suspect Apache Tomcat is causing the RAM overflow.

As you can see, I am concerned about my RAM because it is overflowing into my swap. Is there a reasonable way to limit my RAM usage? Or does my instance not have enough RAM to support a minimal Tomcat server?

At this point, my Geoserver running on Tomcat seems fine except that it is a bit slow sometimes.

Comment: linux control group, cgroup

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724820/tomcat-how-to-limit-the-maximum-memory-tomcat-will-use

Comment: Indeed, cgroups might work, as would limiting the memory in Java, but you have to ask yourself, what do you want it to do when it needs more memory to serve or process a request and can't get it, besides swap? With the Java limit you would just crash Java, not sure what the cgroup limit would cause it to do. But ultimately, I'd say if you want better performance, use a larger instance, micros are very resource limited. (I hope you're not expecting a memory limit to cause the app to need less memory.)